# Negative lookbehind in a regex with an optional prefix

Tags: regex, scala, regex-lookarounds

We are using the following regex to recognize urls (derived from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/gruber/8891611) by [Jim Gruber](http://daringfireball.net/)).  This is being executed in Scala using `scala.util.matching` which in turn uses `java.util.regex`:

```
(?i)\b((?:https?:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.](?!js)[a-z]{2,6}/)(?:[^\s()<>{}\[\]]+)(?:[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])|(?:(?<!@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*[.](?!js)[a-z]{2,6}\b/?(?!@)))
```

This version has escaped forward slashes, for [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/SupR6w3MTx):

```
(?i)\b(((?:https?:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.](?!js)[a-z]{2,6}\/)(?:[^\s()<>{}\[\]]+)(?:[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])|(?:(?<!@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*[.](?!js)[a-z]{2,6}\b\/?(?!@))))
```

Previously the front-end was only sending plaintext to the back end, however now they're allowing users to create anchor tags for urls.  Therefore the back end now needs to recognize urls *except* for those that are already in anchor tags.  I initially tried to accomplish this with a negative loohbehind, ignoring urls with a `href="` prefix

```
(?i)\b((?<!href=")((?:https?: ... etc
```

The problem is that our url regex is very liberal, recognizing `http://www.google.com`, `www.google.com`, and `google.com` - given

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

the negative lookbehind will ignore `http://www.google.com`, but then the regex will still recognize `www.google.com`.  I'm wondering if there's a succinct way to tell the regex "ignore `www.google.com` and `google.com` if they are substrings of an ignored `http(s)://www.google.com`"

At present I'm using a filter on the url regex matches (code is in Scala) - this also ignores urls in link text (`<a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>`) by ignoring urls with a `>` prefix and `</a>` suffix.  I'd rather stick with the filter if doing this in a regex would make an already complicated regex even more unreadable.

```
urlPattern.findAllMatchIn(text).toList.filter(m => {
  val start: Int = m.start(1)
  val end: Int = m.end(1)
  val isHref: Boolean = (start - 6 > 0) && 
    text.substring(start - 6, start) == """href=""""
  val isAnchor: Boolean = (start - 1 > 0 && end + 3 < text.length && 
    text.substring(start - 1, start) == ">" && 
    text.substring(end, end + 3) == "</a>")
  !(isHref || isAnchor) && Option(m.group(1)).isDefined
})
```

Comment: Look into [Possessive Quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) for your particalur regex flavor (eg. `a*+`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href=\S+|\b((?:https?:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.](?!js)[a-z]{2,6}\/)(?:[^\s()<>{}\[\]]+)(?:[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])|(?:(?<!@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*[.](?!js)[a-z]{2,6}\b\/?(?!@)))
```

or

```
<a href=(?:(?!<\/a>).)*<\/a>|\b((?:https?:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.](?!js)[a-z]{2,6}\/)(?:[^\s()<>{}\[\]]+)(?:[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])|(?:(?<!@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*[.](?!js)[a-z]{2,6}\b\/?(?!@)))
```

Try this. What it essentially does is:

1. Consumes all `href` links so that it cannot be matched later
2. Does not capture it so it will not appear in `groups` anyways.
3. Process the rest as before.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vR4fY4/17

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're not only wanting to ignore `www.google.com` and `google.com` if they are substrings of an ignored `http(s)://www.google.com"`, but instead any substring fragments from a previously ignored  section... In which case, you can use a bit of code to work around this! Please see the regex:

```
(a href=")?(?i)\b(((?:https?:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.](?!js)[a-z]{2,6}\/)(?:[^\s()<>{}\[\]]+)(?:[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])|(?:(?<!@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*[.](?!js)[a-z]{2,6}\b\/?(?!@))))
^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm not good at scala but you can probably do this:

```
val links = new Regex("""(a href=")?(?i)\b(((?:https?:... """.r, "unwanted")
val unwanted = for (o <- links findAllMatchIn text) yield o group "unwanted"
```

If `unwanted` is `scala.Null`, then the match is useful.

You can workaround for a need of replacement by replacing an alternative:

```
a href="(?i)\b(?:(?:https?:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.](?!js)[a-z]{2,6}\/)(?:[^\s()<>{}\[\]]+)(?:[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])|(?:(?<!@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*[.](?!js)[a-z]{2,6}\b\/?(?!@)))|((?i)\b(((?:https?:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.](?!js)[a-z]{2,6}\/)(?:[^\s()<>{}\[\]]+)(?:[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])|(?:(?<!@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*[.](?!js)[a-z]{2,6}\b\/?(?!@)))))
```

The second part of the regex behind the pipe `|` is grouped as a capturing group. You can replace by this regex with the first group: `\1`

Similar question:

- [Regex Pattern to Match, Excluding when... / Except between](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/3622940)

Answer (score 0):

How about just adding the `<a href=` part as an optional group, then when checking your matching, you only return those matches in which that group is empty?